# Is there an equivalent of $dbh->sqlite_create_function in DBD::Pg

Tags: postgresql, perl, dbi

I am loving the possibility of creating functions for SQLite in perl with

```
$dbh->sqlite_create_function
```

as documented in [DBD::SQLite](http://search.cpan.org/~ishigaki/DBD-SQLite/lib/DBD/SQLite.pm#$dbh-%3Esqlite_create_function(_$name,_$argc,_$code_ref,_$flags_)) and I'd like to do the same for Postgres. I can't seem to find the same for [DBD::Pg](http://search.cpan.org/dist/DBD-Pg/Pg.pm).

Am I missing something? I know I could do it in the database using `plperl`, but I was looking for a more pure-perl way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DBI is a client library along with all the DBD::xxx.

The reason `sqlite_create_function` works is that SQLite is an embedded database, so the server can access client-side functions directly.

This is not the case with other databases, PostgreSQL including.

The only way to create custom functions when working with other databases is the standard `create function|procedure` on the server side.

Comment: Finger slipped on the phone